# Incident development between periods

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have incidents generated every day - opened that are resolved in same day or month or next month, etc. or removed to infinity period

I need to display status of incidents for particular month how many of them are still opened and how many of them are resolved

I need it to do in Power BI.

I created columns:

**Days Between** according the methodology: https://amitchandak.medium.com/power-query-get-all-dates-between-the-start-and-end-date-9ad6a84cf5f2

**Bridging Period** that checks incidents in the same month - opened/closed expressed by formula:

```
IF ( F_IncidentLast3Months[Created Date] = F_IncidentLast3Months[Days Between], "Opened", IF ( F_IncidentLast3Months[Resolved Date] = F_IncidentLast3Months[Days Between], "Closed", "" ) )
```

**Same Period** that checks incidents closed same day when they were also opened, expressed by formula:

```
IF ( F_IncidentLast3Months[Created Date] = F_IncidentLast3Months[Resolved Date], "Closed", "" )
```

I am not able to handle situation when incident is created for instance on 11.01.2023 and resolved on 15.03.2023 so I need to show the incident as opened in January 23 as well as in February 23 (at the end of February). So in general I need to show incidents as opened that are still not resolved in next periods.

Can you please give me some advice how to do that?

*I have my own code below and I need to clarify that my final output should contain all columns from sourcing table and added extra columns "Resolved" and "Current Opened"*

```
let

//I am sourcing from table with many columns where are also columns Created Date and Resolved Date

Source = database("server", [HierarchicalNavigation=true, Query=" select * from table;"]),

#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Created_Date", type date}, {"Resolved_Date", type date}}),

RenameColumns = Table.TransformColumnNames(#"Changed Type", each Text.Replace(_, "_", " ")),

//I need to put here the logic I explained above before I do another transformations
//At the final I need to have all columns from sourcing table, not only Date, Resolved, CurrentOpened


#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(RenameColumns, {"Config Item Id"}, {{"Group by Config Item Id", each _, type table [Config Item Id=number, Config Item Type Code=text, Config Item Name=nullable text, Data Product Layer=nullable text, Owner Type=nullable text, Owner Name=nullable text, App Steward Type=nullable text, App Steward Name=nullable text, Ticket Url=nullable text, Ticket Id=nullable text, Summary Title=nullable text, Priority Incident=nullable text, Status=nullable text, Assignee Id=nullable text, Reporter Id=nullable text, Created Date=nullable date, Resolved Date=nullable date, Duration=nullable text]}}),

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Group by Config Item Id], "Index", 1)),

#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),

#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Config Item Id", "Config Item Type Code", "Config Item Name", "Data Product Layer", "Owner Type", "Owner Name", "App Steward Type", "App Steward Name", "Ticket Url", "Ticket Id", "Summary Title", "Priority Incident", "Status", "Assignee Id", "Reporter Id", "Created Date", "Created Date Before", "Resolved Date", "Resolved Date After", "Duration", "Days Between", "Index"}, {"Config Item Id", "Config Item Type Code", "Config Item Name", "Data Product Layer", "Owner Type", "Owner Name", "App Steward Type", "App Steward Name", "Ticket Url", "Ticket Id", "Summary Title", "Priority Incident", "Status", "Assignee Id", "Reporter Id", "Created Date", "Created Date Before", "Resolved Date", "Resolved Date After", "Duration", "Days Between", "Index"}),

#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Days Between", type date}, {"Created Date", type date}, {"Resolved Date", type date}, {"Created Date Before", type date}, {"Resolved Date After", type date}})

in
#"Changed Type1"
```

```
INPUT DATASET
```

| App Steward Name | App Steward Type | Assignee Id | Config Item Id | Config Item Name | Config Item Type Code | Ticket Id | Created Date | Resolved Date | Data Product Layer | Duration | Owner Name | Owner Type | Priority Incident | Reporter Id | Status | Summary Title | Ticket Url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_lhoust | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-13526 | 07/12/23 | 07/12/23 | L1 | 4 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Critical | mtax | Closed | SM: Chybějící Statická data v TRH (Available_balance) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-13526 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-12991 | 07/12/23 | 09/12/23 | L1 | 0 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Critical | e_pstupk | Closed | [Shop T24] Oprava SDS tabulky CATEGORY na PROD | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-12991 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-13195 | 08/12/23 | 10/12/23 | L1 | 40 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | e_robruc | Opened | Nesmyslné balance v CRF | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-13195 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |

```
REQUIRED OUTPUT DATASET
```

| App Steward Name | App Steward Type | Assignee Id | Config Item Id | Config Item Name | Config Item Type Code | Ticket Id | Created Date | Resolved Date | Date Between | Opened | Closed | Data Product Layer | Duration | Owner Name | Owner Type | Priority Incident | Reporter Id | Status | Summary Title | Ticket Url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_lhoust | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-13526 | 07/12/23 | 07/12/23 | 07/12/23 | Opened | Closed | L1 | 4 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Critical | mtax | Closed | SM: Chybějící Statická data v TRH (Available_balance) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-13526 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-12991 | 07/12/23 | 09/12/23 | 07/12/23 | Opened |  | L1 | 0 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Critical | e_pstupk | Closed | [Shop T24] Oprava SDS tabulky CATEGORY na PROD | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-12991 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-12991 | 07/12/23 | 09/12/23 | 08/12/23 |  |  | L1 | 0 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Critical | e_pstupk | Closed | [Shop T24] Oprava SDS tabulky CATEGORY na PROD | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-12991 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-12991 | 07/12/23 | 09/12/23 | 09/12/23 |  | Closed | L1 | 0 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Critical | e_pstupk | Closed | [Shop T24] Oprava SDS tabulky CATEGORY na PROD | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-12991 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-13195 | 08/12/23 | 10/12/23 | 08/12/23 | Opened |  | L1 | 40 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | e_robruc | Opened | Nesmyslné balance v CRF | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-13195 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-13195 | 08/12/23 | 10/12/23 | 09/12/23 |  |  | L1 | 40 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | e_robruc | Opened | Nesmyslné balance v CRF | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-13195 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | e_pstupk | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ESCB-13195 | 08/12/23 | 10/12/23 | 10/12/23 |  | Closed | L1 | 40 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | e_robruc | Opened | Nesmyslné balance v CRF | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ESCB-13195 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 25/10/23 | Opened |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 26/10/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 27/10/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 28/10/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 29/10/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 30/10/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 31/10/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 01/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 02/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 03/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 04/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 05/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 06/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 07/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 08/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 09/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 10/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 11/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 12/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 13/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 14/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 15/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 16/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 17/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 18/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 19/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 20/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 21/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 22/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 23/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 24/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 25/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 26/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 27/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 28/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 29/11/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 30/11/23 | Opened |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 01/12/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 02/12/23 |  |  | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |
| Core banking system replacement | Squad | roliva | 1 | T24.TDP | CO | ICM-30654 | 25/10/23 | 03/12/23 | 03/12/23 |  | Closed | L1 | 9 | Enterprise Services Tribe | OrgUnit | Non-Critical | JIRAUSER47719 | Closed | D_T24 wfdi_T24_SDS_2_LSS_LSS Failed(25.10.2023) | https://jira.kb.cz/jira/browse/ICM-30654 |

Comment: With regard to your edit, you right, you want the output table to show all the columns from your source table. Table. However, your screenshot of your output does not show any columns from your original source table. Please resolve.

Comment: Please post data as text which can be easily copy pasted. There is a markdown tables generator which can be used to assist in this. Your desired output can be a screenshot, but the data itself should be posted as text.

Comment: I posted data as text, just for clarification, in situation of incident resolved date 31.12.2999, created for instance 09.09.2023, the incident is marked as opened in every month till 31.12.2999. But if is resolved for instance in 01.12.2023, incident is marked as opened in 09.09.2023, 31.10.2023, 30.11.2023.

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Why isn't ICM-30654 marked as Opened on 31-Oct-2023? Why are you generating this expanded table of dates at all, if what you really want is a table of the Open and Resolved items by month? And if that is what you want, why only mark the start and the beginning of each month as Opened. So far as handling the 31-12-2999 just transform that to something like the today's date (or the maximum date in the table) to that date +1, and then filter it out at that last date at the end.

Comment: ICM-30654 was opened 25/10/23 so there is no need to have same status at the end of same month. We check ultimo at the end of month for next period since ICM was created. ICM was opened in Oct, in Nov there is no status close, so for ultimo (end of month) should be status opened (ICM is still opened). In Dec ICM was closed, so there is no need to check ultimo.

Comment: I need to have expanded table in this form because overview of opened and closed items by month is one of the visuals I use in report. I need to filter the visual according to App Steward Name, Config Item Name (development of opened and closed ICM according to Config Item Name) etc., so that is the reason I need the table in this form.

Comment: OK I think I understand. I have added different code to the end of my existing answer to accomodate your new examples. So far as the never closed instance, how would you want to have that handled? Please provide an example. I'll edit in a little bit to show one way, but it would be useful for you to specify what you want to happen.

Comment: For 1900-01-01 I would set date as second lowest Create Date minus 12 months and for 2999-12-31 I would set date as second highest Resolved Date plus 12 months. 
Eg. highest resolved date is 2023-12-26, so date for "infinity" will be set as 2024-12-26. So Infinity date will be shifted with increasing date till it is closed in the future.

Comment: suggest using the algorithm shown in my code below. Except that if you enter a Resolved Date of `1900-01-01` you could programatically enter it as some time in the future. If not, **you** can change the algorithm. Doing it your way, with the algorithm I have shown will result in, in my opinion, huge tables that are 12 months longer than they need to be for the infinity dates, instead of just ending at Today with the incident never showing `Closed`.

Comment: Easiest way to handle `1900-01-01` using my algorithm would be to add a condition to the `Date Between` algorithm to also check if the `Resolved Date` is less than `Create Date` then use `Today`

Comment: I edited my code so it will assume an incident is not closed if  `Resolved Date` > `Today` or if `Resolved Date` < `Created Date`. As before, the latest date being shown will be `Today`. This should work for unless you need to have the table extend past `TODAY` in which case you should edit the `#"Add Date Between"` step.

Comment: It looks great! Remaining how to handle Create Date. Initial logic for Create Date and Resolved Date is: coalesce(Create Date, date '1900-01-01'), coalesce(Resolved Date, date '2999-12-31'). If algorithm handles Resolved Date '2999-12-31' as you described above, is it possible to handle Create date? Eg. second lowest Create Date (first is '1900-01-01') and since this date is incident opened till the Resolved Date is <= Today?

Comment: Anything is possible. But I cannot continually be hitting a moving target. That is not how this forum works. The question you have asked, and then amended, has apparently been answered. If you have a new problem, I suggest you close this question out by accepting the answer to the question you asked; try to solve your new problem and, if you cannot, present it clearly and completely as a new question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your help! I appreciate your knowledge and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edited to address your revised problem statement***
Your revised output table, from your revised sample, can be addressed by the following code, I think:
*Note: this handles non-closed incidents by assuming that the an incident will not be shown as `Closed` if it is resolved in the future or if the Resolved Date is prior to Created Date.*

```
let

//change next lines to reflect actual data source and column headers
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"App Steward Name", type text}, {"App Steward Type", type text}, {"Assignee Id", type text}, 
        {"Config Item Id", Int64.Type}, {"Config Item Name", type text}, {"Config Item Type Code", type text}, 
        {"Ticket Id", type text}, {"Created Date", type date}, {"Resolved Date", type date}, 
        {"Data Product Layer", type text}, {"Duration", Int64.Type}, {"Owner Name", type text}, 
        {"Owner Type", type text}, {"Priority Incident", type text}, {"Reporter Id", type text}, 
        {"Status", type text}, {"Summary Title", type text}, {"Ticket Url", type text}}),
    
//Date Between column will have a maximum date of "Today"
//Resolved Dates that are after TODAY are ignored
//Resolved Dates that are before Created Date are ignored
    #"Add Date Between" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date Between", each 
        List.Dates(
                [Created Date], 
                Duration.Days(
                    List.Min({
                        if [Resolved Date] < [Created Date] 
                            then Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) 
                        else [Resolved Date]
                    , 
                    Date.From(DateTime.FixedLocalNow())})-[Created Date])+1,
                #duration(1,0,0,0)), 
                type {date}),
    #"Expanded Date Between" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Add Date Between", "Date Between"),

//Index column added to preserve original data order
    #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Expanded Date Between","sortIndex",0,1,Int64.Type),

//Rows grouped by Ticket ID
//You could group by additional columns if necessary
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Index", {"Ticket Id"}, {
            {"Closed/Open", (t)=>let

    //Note that Date Between will never = Resolved date if Resolved date is in the future 
                #"Add Closed" = Table.AddColumn(#"t","Closed", 
                    each if [Date Between]=[Resolved Date] then "Closed" else null, type text),

    //Opened date should always be the first date in the list which is the beginning of the Created Date list
                #"Add Opened" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Closed","Opened", 
                    each if [Date Between]=[Created Date] then "Opened" else null, type text),
                #"First Month Start" = Date.StartOfMonth(#"Add Opened"[Date Between]{0}),

    //If the End Of Month "Open" slot is not in the first month, then print "Open" there.
    //  UNLESS it is Closed on that date
                #"EOM Open" = Table.ReplaceValue(
                    #"Add Opened",
                    each [Date Between],//y
                    each [Closed], //z
                    (x,y,z)=> if y = Date.EndOfMonth(y) 
                                    and Date.StartOfMonth(y) <> #"First Month Start"
                                    and z <> "Closed"
                                then "Opened" 
                                else x,
                    {"Opened"} //x                
                )
                    in #"EOM Open"}}),
   
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Ticket Id"}),
    #"Expanded Closed/Open" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Closed/Open", {"App Steward Name", "App Steward Type", "Assignee Id", "Config Item Id", "Config Item Name", "Config Item Type Code", "Ticket Id", "Created Date", "Resolved Date", "Data Product Layer", "Duration", "Owner Name", "Owner Type", "Priority Incident", "Reporter Id", "Status", "Summary Title", "Ticket Url", "Date Between", "sortIndex", "Closed", "Opened"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Closed/Open",{{"sortIndex", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"sortIndex"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"App Steward Name", type text}, {"App Steward Type", type text}, {"Assignee Id", type text}, {"Config Item Id", Int64.Type}, {"Config Item Name", type text}, {"Config Item Type Code", type text}, {"Ticket Id", type text}, {"Created Date", type date}, {"Resolved Date", type date}, {"Data Product Layer", type text}, {"Duration", Int64.Type}, {"Owner Name", type text}, {"Owner Type", type text}, {"Priority Incident", type text}, {"Reporter Id", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Summary Title", type text}, {"Ticket Url", type text}, {"Date Between", type date}, {"Closed", type text}, {"Opened", type text}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"App Steward Name", "App Steward Type", "Assignee Id", "Config Item Id", "Config Item Name", "Config Item Type Code", "Ticket Id", "Created Date", "Resolved Date", "Date Between", "Opened", "Closed", "Data Product Layer", "Duration", "Owner Name", "Owner Type", "Priority Incident", "Reporter Id", "Status", "Summary Title", "Ticket Url"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

***Output from your second data set***
*Note: This screenshot shows only a few columns, but **ALL** columns are retained*
[image]